# Why do I get "index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0" for a large dataset but not for a small dataset?

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LE7jd.png)

```
<ipython-input-46-4dc0f8b3e097> in number_of_real_and_fake_videos(data_list)
      8   for i in data_list:
      9     temp_video = i.split('/')[-1]
---> 10     label = lab.iloc[(labels.loc[labels["file"] == temp_video].index.values[0]),1]
     11     if(label == 'FAKE'):
     12       fake+=1

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

I am getting this error but when I use small dataset it will give output but for a large dataset it will show an index error.

Comment: Without information on used libraries or data type you have here, there's no way of answering this question.

Comment: I'm assuming by the way you index you're using a pandas dataframe. It'd be worth clarifying that in the question to help with answers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when you run the line `labels.loc[labels["file"] == temp_video].index.values[0]` within your loop you run into the situation where there are no values in `labesl["file"]` matching `temp_video`. This leaves you with an empty array, which can't return anything for the element at index position `0`. To simplify, here's your error:

```py
import pandas as pd

empty_df = pd.DataFrame([])
empty_df.index.values[0]
```

which gives you:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <module>
----> 1 empty_df.index.values[0]

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

To fix this, you could try checking that there are matches before calling the value:

```py
for i in data_list:    
    temp_video = i.split('/')[-1]
    temp_video_filter = labels.loc[labels["file"] == temp_video]
    if len(temp_video_filter > 0):
        label = lab.iloc[(temp_video_filter.index.values[0]),1]
        if(label == 'FAKE'):
            fake+=1
```

I suspect there is a way to solve your problem with the pandas api without using the for loop, so you may want to look into that also.